# Embedded C programming - Renesas

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on Renesas RL78 family. I am developing an application to handle read and write to Data Flash Memory.

I need to write an array, say `int a[3] = {0,1,2};`

Now I pass the address of this array to the function which writes to actual data flash memory. But I see that my array contents are modified when `FAL_Init()` function gets executed.

But if instead of this, if I initialize my array at run time then it seems to have no effect.

I do not exactly understand what is happening inside `FAL_Init()` function as it is a library provided function and I have no access to it.

Please help me in finding what could be causing this.

I am posting my code:

```
//ptrData contains my received value

status = FAL_Init((__far fal_descriptor_t*)&fal_descriptor_str )

//ptrData contents are modified

FAL_Open();

//there is erase command here

buffer[0] = ptrData[0]; // I am receiving data here.
```

Comment: What `FAL_Init` return? It success or return an error?  Post your code, please.

Comment: Could you post your functions calls : `FAL_Init()`, `FAL_Open()` and `FAL_Execute()`?

Comment: You are writing literal data from a flash page into a flash page?  I can see an issue with that..

Comment: @MartinJames array is RAM stored.

Comment: Just speculating: could it be that this is a local array, but the flash writes are executed by repeated interrupt calls? I.e the flash programming driver does not buffer the data internally, but uses the passed pointer to data. And then the local array goes out of scope before the function is done.

Comment: Hi all,my array is global varible. N FAl_Init() returns success. Below is my code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. It was the issue of allocating RAM. FAL_init() code gets executed from RAM. So when this portion of code was getting executed, if my array variables were stored in same location, they were getting over written. Changed allocation of FAL functions with linker and it solved the issue. Thanks everyone